# Error "Auto offset commit failed: [Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError:" after days of use

Tags: python, apache-kafka, aiokafka

This problem always occurs after a few days that microservices communicate with kafka, I have 3 nodes, and for each microservice I use a group id on a specific topic. The error is as follows.

```
Unable connect to node with id 1:
Failed fetch messages from 1: NodeNotReadyError: Attempt to send a request to node which is not ready (node id 1).
Failed fetch messages from 2: [Error 7] RequestTimedOutError
Failed fetch messages from 1: [Error 7] RequestTimedOutError
Failed fetch messages from 2: [Error 7] RequestTimedOutError
Error sending JoinGroupRequest_v2 to node 1 [[Error 7] RequestTimedOutError] -- marking coordinator dead
Marking the coordinator dead (node 1)for group _message_alarm_ticket_app1.
Failed fetch messages from 3: [Error 7] RequestTimedOutError
Heartbeat failed: local member_id was not recognized; resetting and re-joining group
Heartbeat session expired - marking coordinator dead
Marking the coordinator dead (node 3)for group nce_alarms.
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
OffsetCommit failed for group nce_alarms due to group error ([Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms), will rejoin
Auto offset commit failed: [Error 25] UnknownMemberIdError: nce_alarms
```

**Describe Topic**

```
root@dev-s-kafka1:/opt/kafka/bin# ./kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic nce_alarms
Topic: nce_alarms       TopicId: zDniSSlUTgS4bWyXKPg5Zw PartitionCount: 8       ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
        Topic: nce_alarms       Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: nce_alarms       Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: nce_alarms       Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 2,3,1
        Topic: nce_alarms       Partition: 3    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: nce_alarms       Partition: 4    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,3,2 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: nce_alarms       Partition: 5    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,1,3 Isr: 2,3,1
        Topic: nce_alarms       Partition: 6    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 3,2,1
        Topic: nce_alarms       Partition: 7    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 2,3,1
```

**Environment**

- aiokafka version 0.8.0
- kafka-python version 2.0.2:
- Kafka Broker version 3.0.0:
- Python version 3.9.16

If more information is needed please let me know, unfortunately I have only recently started working on this project, but I can ask my colleagues.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using async commit or auto commit in the code?

Comment: Hi @AvishekBhattacharya On aiokafka, in the AIOKafkaConsumer() method, Is everything by default.

Comment: Have you solved your issue? I've encountered the same

Comment: @cyberbudy no, I'm sorry.